# h:inputText allow only numbers during input

Tags: jsf-2, numbers, richfaces

I have a field in JSF2, I tried execute a validation in this way:

```
<h:inputText value="#{manutencaoContratoBean.contrato.nuContrato}" style="text-align: left; width: 90%; ">
<f:convertNumber pattern="#######" maxFractionDigits="0" maxIntegerDigits="16"/>
```

And thus:

```
<h:inputText value="#{manutencaoContratoBean.contrato.nuContrato}" style="text-align: left; width: 90%; ">
  <f:convertNumber integerOnly="true"/
```

However, my field only makes a validation and show me a message, I would like just the insertion of numbers, not Strings, this is possible ?

Is possible a insertion only of numbers ? I'm using RichFaces 4, if that's relevant.

I found this, it´s work well:

```
onkeypress="if(event.which &lt; 48 || event.which &gt; 57) return false;"
```

But this not allow a click on the backspace button, in case the user make a mistake.

Thanks in advance for all !

Comment: Primefaces InputNumber

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finished using this function:

```
onkeypress="if(event.which &lt; 48 || event.which &gt; 57 ) if(event.which != 8) return false;"
```

This work well in IE and Chrome, I don´t know why it´s not work well in firefox too, this function block the tab key in Firefox.

For the tab key work fine in firefox add this:

```
onkeypress="if(event.which &lt; 48 || event.which &gt; 57 ) if(event.which != 8) if(e.keyCode != 9) return false;"
```

Thanks for all.

Comment: Did you actualle search stackoverflow before posting a question? I've seen several duplicates

Comment: Yes, I did,  I did not find the post that you suggest, sorry for this, I will pay more attention in the next time.